# React Native Expo Push Notification Badge Not Going Away

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I’ve developed two apps in React Native using Expo Build and published them on both app stores. I use Expo Push Notifications on both apps.

This is how I set badge count:

```
useGetNotificationsCount.js

useEffect(() => {
    setNotificationsCount(localUser?.userId > 0 ? notifications?.items?.filter(n => !n.isRead)?.length : 0);
}, [notifications, localUser]);
```

```
appNavigation.js

useEffect(() => {
    if (notificationsCount) {
      Notifications.setBadgeCountAsync(notificationsCount);
    }
}, [notificationsCount]);
```

```
Tab.Navigation:
     
      <Tab.Screen
        name={appRoutes.NOTIFICATIONS_STACK}
        component={NotificationsStack}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <AFIonIcon name='notifications-outline' color={color} size={size} />,
          tabBarBadge: notificationsCount || undefined,
          headerShown: false,
          unmountOnBlur: true,
          tabBarStyle: {
            height: moderateScale(80, 0.3),
            backgroundColor: appColors.BACKGROUND_BLUE,
            borderTopWidth: 0,
          },
        }}
      />
```

A while ago the badge stuck on the iOS app icon and won’t go away no matter what I do. I’ve republished the apps on TestFlight and then in App Store several times and each time I delete the app from my iPhone and reinstall it but as soon as it’s installed the badge returns even before I open the brand new clean app to sign up or to use it.

I suspect that the problem is related to the device or one of the dummy user Id’s I’ve been using to test the apps. I’ve been using my iPhone and my wife’s as well as my iPad for testing and it’s the same on all devices. Problem is that I’ve tried many different ways to get rid of the badge for good but it just keeps returning. The ExpoPushToken database is empty on all my database servers. And I can’t find where to view or clear it on Expo or APN, if they exist.

Any ideas on how to get rid of it permanently?

I’ve verified that the app isn’t setting the badge for some unknown reason.
I’ve even tried dismissAllNotifications.
I’ve made sure the database storing my ExpoPushTokens is empty.
I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled the app.
I’ve bounced the notifications permission for the app on the device.
I don’t have an Android device so I’m not sure if it does the same.
I’m pretty sure it’s the two iPhones, not other users’ devices.

It just keeps returning on both apps and both devices as soon as I release a new version to the store and install them.